# How to change the color of a white sprite using HEX values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to change the color of a white sprite using script.
I have the HEX valve which I convert into RGB and try to change the color of the sprite.
The color gets changed but it is not exactly what I require.
It changes to some random color.
Below is the code which I'm Trying, I can't understand where I'm going wrong.
Please Help me out.
Thank You.

```
    string tempColor;
    tempColor = "E2270A";
    Color m_NewColor;
    float m_Red, m_Green, m_Blue;
    m_Red = System.Convert.ToInt32 (tempColor.Substring (0, 2), 16);
    m_Green = System.Convert.ToInt32 (tempColor.Substring (2, 2), 16);
    m_Blue = System.Convert.ToInt32 (tempColor.Substring (4, 2), 16);

    m_NewColor = new Color (m_Red, m_Green, m_Blue);
    Animinstance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = m_NewColor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply just call [`ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html) api , But should add '#'

```
Color color;
if( ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#E2270A", out color))
{
    Animinstance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color;
}
```

Comment: didn't know about that but it seems to be the best one! Up you go ;)

Answer (score 1):

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896737/7111561) mentioned [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) takes `float` values `0.0f - 1.0f` so simply devide your values by `255f` in order to map them to the according `float` (%) value .

---

Or you can simply use [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) instead which takes `byte` values `0-255`

```
var tempColor = "E2270A";
var m_Red = System.Convert.ToByte(tempColor.Substring(0, 2), 16);
var m_Green = System.Convert.ToByte(tempColor.Substring(2, 2), 16);
var m_Blue = System.Convert.ToByte(tempColor.Substring(4, 2), 16);

// always requires the alpha parameter
var m_NewColor = new UnityEngine.Color32(m_Red, m_Green, m_Blue, 255);
Animinstance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = m_NewColor;
```

> [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) can be implicitly converted to and from [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html), you'll note that the example takes `float` values:

```
Color newColor = new Color(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 0.3f); // r, g, b, a
```

or

```
Color newColor = new Color(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f); // r, g, b
```

We can conclude from the examples that `Color` expects valeus between 0 (0x00 in your hex string) and 1 (0xFF), but the integer values of these hex values are 0-255. We therefore need to divide them by 255 to get values between 0 and 1:

```
string tempColor;
tempColor = "E2270A";
Color m_NewColor;
float m_Red, m_Green, m_Blue;
m_Red = System.Convert.ToSingle (tempColor.Substring (0, 2), 16) / 255.0f;
m_Green = System.Convert.ToSingle (tempColor.Substring (2, 2), 16) / 255.0f;
m_Blue = System.Convert.ToSingle (tempColor.Substring (4, 2), 16) / 255.0f;

m_NewColor = new Color (m_Red, m_Green, m_Blue);
Animinstance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = m_NewColor;
```